# combine pngs images with transparency into a video and merge it on a static image

Tags: ffmpeg, video, png, transparency

I'm trying to combine multiple png frames into a video with ffmpeg, keeping the transparency, to then combine it with an image. The png video comes with a black background so when i try to combine it with an image, the image is completely overlayed by the black background, how can I keep the transparency?

Here's the command I use to combine the PNGs:

```
ffmpeg -y -i src/tmp/%d.png -c:v libx264 -vf fps=25 -pix_fmt yuva420p land.mov
```

I already tried also with `ffmpeg -y -i src/tmp/%d.png -c copy land.mov` as suggested by another user but the video is corrupted

Comment: `... -c:v prores -pix_fmt yuva444p10le land.mov`

Comment: @andyts93 did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a video codec that supports transparency a.k.a. alpha channel. `libx264` doesn't. A bunch of them do, I haven't found a complete list, but you can find many names e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644684/turn-image-sequence-into-video-with-transparency).

For `.mov` format the most suitable one would be `png` considering you're converting from those. `prores` is also a good option.

Set the codec with `-c:v`.